# Strange behaviour of ServerSocket.accept method

Tags: java, sockets

I created class SocketListener to receive data through TCP protocol. My start method looks like this:

```
public void start() throws IOException {
LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "SOCKET LISTENER STARTED PORT: " + port);
serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
while (true) {
  FrameParser fp;
  try {
    socket = serverSocket.accept(); 
    fp = new FrameParser(socket);
    Thread thread = new Thread(fp);
    thread.start();
  } catch (Exception e) {
    resetConnection();
  }
}
```

}

Writing this code I based on example from oracle website (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/socket-140484.html#server). When I placed line with serverSocket.accept() inside loop some of the packets was not received by ServerSocket. I am sure that this TCP packets was received on my network interface bacause I checked it later using Wireshark. I have no idea what causes that problem so I tried different things and I noticed that more packets was received when I change my code like this:

```
public void start() throws IOException {
LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "SOCKET LISTENER STARTED PORT: " + port);
serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
socket = serverSocket.accept();
while (true) {
  FrameParser fp;
  try {
    fp = new FrameParser(socket);
    Thread thread = new Thread(fp);
    thread.start();
  } catch (Exception e) {
    resetConnection();
  }
}
```

}

I made this modification using trial and error method and unfortunately after this change my application started receive more data than I filtered in Wireshark (for example in Wireshark I saw 10 packets but my application created hundreds of new threads and it finished with out of memory error).

What can be a reason that in a first case not all of TCP packets reached to socket?

Comment: You are accepting twice in your first version. So the first connection is accepted and discarded, and then you accept the second connection. You should only have one accept in each loop iteration.

Comment: Now you edited the code you put in first place, are you sure this is the code you're using now?

Comment: I made a mistake writing this post, I have already changed it. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Yes, this is how my code looks like now. Like I said it's similar to Example 2: Multithreaded Server Example from url which I mention in my post.